# Is JSPF validation broken in IBM RAD 8?

Tags: java, validation, jsp, jspinclude, ibm-rad

My IBM RAD 8 is not working when it is supposed to validate a JSP fragment. It reports errors that classes and variables are undefined that are defined in the including file. I don't want to disable validation, I'm asking how to enable it. I name my JSP fragment .jspf and put it in the recommended WEB-INF/jspf and then validation is supposed to work but it doesn't. The only answer from IBM was how to disable validation of JSPF fragments: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21284702
Is it really broken?

I include my file this way

```
<div class="popup" id="popupSokNamn" 
<% if(!showSearch) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/namnuppgifter_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
```

and then IBM RAD can't validate the jspf file. Is validation broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several open bugs on Eclipse WTP for JSPF : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=JSPF

The first one : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=155664 explains why validating them is so hard.